# Flattening with missing or no results

Tags: google-bigquery

I am pretty new to Bigquery and I would like to unnest 2 tables in one query.

I tried to query below code but it did not work. It gave me this message: "This query returned no results".

```
SELECT
    timestamp AS Date,
    A.key,
    B.name
FROM `pms_table_request_log.partners_request_log_*`,
     UNNEST(jsonPayload.response.body.channels) AS A,
     UNNEST(jsonPayload.response.body.data.rows) AS B;
```

I expect key and name to be unnested.

Comment: Could you please fix the formatting of the SQL in your question?

Comment: Sorry I am pretty new here too - formatting is now fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If with unnesting you mean to "flatten", which means to bring data from array fields to top level, you can try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `CROSS JOIN` (which is the comma)

```
SELECT timestamp AS Date ,A.key ,B.name 
FROM pms_table_request_log.partners_request_log_* 
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(jsonPayload.response.body.channels) AS A 
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(jsonPayload.response.body.data.rows) AS B
```

If any of the array is empty, `CROSS JOIN` would destroy the whole row while `LEFT JOIN` preserves the left "table"

Comment: Thank you very much martin. You are a star. It's working now :)

Comment: I came across the same problem, and I would like to express my gratitude towards your answer, Martin. @Martin Weitzmann